# How to find Cassandra coordinator node using java

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

When I create a session for Cassandra cluster using datastax driver Cluster java class, I need to find for a particular session which data node is used as coordinator node.

I tried session.getState().getConnectedHosts() but this is giving all data nodes in my cluster.

Actually at one point of time there will be only one coordinator node which is used. Can anyone please help me to find the coordinator node with java code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running a query, ResultSet.getExecutionInfo() returns ExecutionInfo. 
http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html

This has the coordinator host you're after.
http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ExecutionInfo.html#getQueriedHost()